# How can I solve This using First and Follow rules in Compiler?

Tags: compiler-construction

How Can I Solve This Grammar Using First and Follow rules ?

```
S → ABC
A → a | ε
B → b | ε
C → c | ε
```

Comment: There is no canonical way to *solve* a grammar. You can calculate the First and Follow sets for the grammar, and these can be used to create a parser for the grammar. See this post on [calculating Nullable, First, Follow and Lookahead](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13731963/235908) for a grammar.